# Error using Firebase, installed with pod, on xCode 10-beta 1

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods, swift3, xcode8

I am using Firebase for my swift 3 project. I am using pod to install it. This is my pod file:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'Firebasetest' do

  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

When i run `pod install`, I get this error message:

> [!] The `Aksjeblikk [Release]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Aksjeblikk/Pods-Aksjeblikk.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>
> Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or 
> Remove the build settings from the target.

In Xcode-beta, i can't find the `import Firebase` option, only `import FirebaseMessaging`, and some other, see image:[image] When i write the `import Firebase`, i get this error message: [image]
The question is: How can i import Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You've to add `$(inherited)` flag like so:

```
Go to your target Build Settings -> Other linker flags -> double click . Add `$(inherited)` to a new line.
```

Try and check if it works. It will most of the times.

Comment: For which of the projects?